# Implementing inner traits in Scala like we do with inner interfaces in Java

Tags: java, scala, inner-classes

This code in Java compiles without errors:

```
interface T {
    interface Q {
    }
}

class C implements T.Q {
}
```

whereas this code in Scala does not:

```
trait T {
    trait Q {
    }
}

class C extends T.Q {
}
```

What is the correct translation (if it exists) of the Java code listing into Scala?

Theoretical explanations about language design are welcome.

Comment: In addition to what others have already answered about path-dependent types, it is also worth noting that Scala's notation for Java's `T.Q` is `T#Q`.

Comment: The `T#Q` syntax Oleg referred to is called a [type projection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676048/why-does-one-select-scala-type-members-with-a-hash-instead-of-a-dot).  And note that you *can* extend Q if you do it within a type derived from T, e.g. `class A extends T { class B extends Q }`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The inner type `Q` is defined only for specific instance implementation of the `T` trait. Since scala has *path-dependent* types, each instance of `T` will have his own subtrait `Q`.

```
scala> trait T {
     |   trait Q
     | }
defined trait T

scala> class C extends T {
     |   def getQ: this.Q = new this.Q {}
     | }
defined class C

scala> val inC = (new C).getQ
inC: C#Q = C$$anon$1@3f53073a


scala> val c = new C
c: C = C@1a7e4ff0

scala> new c.Q {}
res4: c.Q = $anon$1@36bbb2f5
```

---

If you need an interface for a generic behavior for your clients to implement, and not dependent on a specific `C` instance, you should define it within an `Object`

```
scala> object T {
     |   trait Q {
     |     def implementMe: Unit
     |   }
     | }
defined module T

scala> val inT = new T.Q {
     |   def implementMe = println("implemented!")
     | }
inT: T.Q = $anon$1@20f2a08b

scala> inT.implementMe
implemented!
```

---

**Why path-dependent types?**

As for the design reasons, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581836/why-does-scala-have-path-dependent-types)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that. When types are nested you're creating what is called a *path-dependent type*, meaning the type of each instance of the inner entity is tied to the specific instance within which it's constructed.

In other words, you interface Q has no independent existence that would allow you to refer to it apart from an instance of T.