# Referring to trait inside trait

Tags: scala, types, traits, inner-classes, type-projection

What do I need the type of `x` to be in the following code to be able to refer to `x.f` in `g()`? `A.B` didn't work.

```
trait A {
    trait B {
        def f: Unit
    }
}

object O {
    def g(x : ?): Unit {
        x.f
    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly useful: [Implementing inner traits in Scala like we do with inner interfaces in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614849/implementing-inner-traits-in-scala-like-we-do-with-inner-interfaces-in-java)

Comment: `def g(x: A#B): Unit = { x.f }`

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: @jwvh Or with a finer type `def g(x: a.B forSome {val a: A}): Unit = { x.f }`

Comment: @DmytroMitin existential types [are no longer](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/dropped-features/existential-types.html) supported in scala 3 :) I think projection (A#B) it is better for now, isn't?

Comment: @gianlucaaguzzi It's not clear whether OP asks about Scala 2 or Scala 3. Existential types (not wildcarded) are no longer supported. General projections (with abstract `A`) are not either (for traits `A#B` is ok). Projections are not better or worse than existentials, they are just different.

Comment: @gianlucaaguzzi Scala 2.12, although I'd rather not add in features that are going to be deprecated in Scala 3 (I'd like to upgrade at some point)