# Misunderstanding with type checks in Scala

Tags: scala

I have simple type hierarchy in Scala:

```
trait A {
    trait A1
}

object B extends A {
    case object B1 extends A1
}

object C extends A {
    case object C1 extends A1
}
```

And, I'm gonna use these types like that:

```
def get(): Any = C.C1

get() match {
    case _: B.A1 => println("B")
    case _: C.A1 => println("C")
    case _: A#A1 => println("Any")
}
```

Surprisingly, I'm getting `B` printed (I've expected `C`).

Why compiler treats `C.C1` as instance of `B.A1`?

Comment: I guess this is a problem of type erasure, try `scalac -Xprint:erasure`, your pattern match get compiled to `A.A1`

Comment: @Zoltán http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#equivalence

Comment: @HerringtonDarkholme I don't think these are [compound types](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/110), but [path-dependent types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581836/why-does-scala-have-path-dependent-types). In any case, my assumption is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known bug.

Scalac *does* generate a warning for this using the `-unchecked` flag:

```
warning: The outer reference in this type test cannot be checked at run time.
            case _: B.A1 => println("B")
                  ^
```

So right now, `B.A1` and `C.A1` appear the same to the compiler in the pattern match, because it doesn't check the outer reference to `B` or `C`.

See this [related discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-internals/vw8Kek4zlZ8/LAeakfeR3RoJ).

And [SI-4440](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4440)

Comment: It definitely looks like a bug in compiler. I thought about it, but decided I'm missing something. I really like Scala, and hope this issue will be fixed in future releases.

Comment: Though, I didn't manage to get this warning, while playing with `-unchecked` flag. Tried Scala 2.10.5 and 2.11.7.

Comment: I didn't get it in the REPL, but I did if I put the same code in a scala file and compiled with scalac.

Comment: Right, I've got that warn with `scalac` 2.11.7. Previously, I've tried to compile with SBT. Well, nice to know: at least compiler warns you about the problem :)